# IPMI beginner's tutorial / GPU fan speed adjustment

Tags: fedora, gpu, cooling, temperature, fedora-17

I have a workstation equipped with two Kepler K20M GPUs that doesn't have active fans installed on them. There is one external fan attached to the rear of the chassis extracting the exhaust. However the fan is controlled by IPMI, which respond to the chassis temperature rather than the actual GPU temperature and the GPUs are always over-heating because of this. I've tried to install IPMI tools to manage this, however these are all command-line tools that are not so friendly to beginners. So I'm wondering if someone can recommend a way for me to learn about this, or any shortcut to control the GPU temperature? Thanks!

OS: Fedora 17.
Mother Board: Supermicro.